# Spread Operator to get single property of objects inside an Array - JS/TS

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Lets say I have:

```
const arr = [
  {label: 1, value: "One"},
  {label: 2, value: "two"}
}
```

I want to get `value` out of it as an arrar of string,

Traditional way:

```
const strArr = [];
arr.forEach(ele => {strArr.push(ele.value)});
console.log(strArr);
```

But can I do it using spread operator or any other way ?

Comment: use map method...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method.

```js
const arr = [{
    label: 1,
    value: "One"
  },
  {
    label: 2,
    value: "two"
  }
]

let res = arr.map(o => o.value)
// or in case you want to create an object with only value 
// property then you can use Destructuring
// .map(({ value }) => ({ value }))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Or better `arr.map(v => v.value)` <- one of those cases when destructuring makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 6):

I would use .map() in this case as well. But if you really wanted to use a spread operator you could do this.

```
const arr = [
  {label: 1, value: "One"},
  {label: 2, value: "two"}
];

const res = []

for (let obj of arr) {
  res = [...res, obj.value]
}
console.log(res)
```

Comment: One nitpick: `const res = []` should be `let` since it's being changed below its instantiation. Otherwise this works nicely!

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) by defining a mapping function:

```js
const arr = [
  {label: 1, value: "One"},
  {label: 2, value: "two"}
];

const vals = Array.from(arr, o => o.value);
console.log(vals);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it using spread operator. Use `map()` instead.

```js
const arr = [{label: 1, value: "One"}, {label: 2, value: "two"}]

const res = arr.map(x => x.value);
console.log(res)
```